# Локальная установка пакета с помощью composer

Tags: composer, package, install, require, packagist

Хочу установить пакет  с помощью composer, ввожу:

```
composer global require package-name
```

устанавливается пакет с именем package-name с packagist.org, а мне нужно чтобы установился мой локальный пакет с именем package-name.

Подскажите, как объяснить composer, что нужно устанавливать локальный пакет, а не с packagist.org?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить дополнительный репозиторий, в котором composer будет искать пакеты для установки вначале, а если там не найдет - продолжит искать в packagist.org

1. Добавить локальный репозиторий:

```
composer config repositories.foo vcs </path/to/repo/foo/bar.git | https://example.com/foo/bar.git>
```

2. Подключить пакет из локального репозитория (ветка - master):

```
composer require foo/bar:dev-master
```